# .bat loop through directory, pass file names to executable as arguments

Tags: batch-file

The executable I am running simply wants a file name as a parameter

```
@echo off
FOR  %%i IN (C:\Files\*.*) DO (
echo %%~nxi
start "mass extract.." "C:\Files\extractor.exe" %%~nxi
)
```

despite only returning the file names themselves, its not passing it to my exe as a parameter correctly, what am I missing?

Comment: The best is to use `"%%~fi"`; so you won't have trouble with paths containing whitespaces; (the modifier `~f` is enough, you do not need `~fnx` as the output is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the working directory to extractor or the full path of each files.

3 ways:

**method #1**

Use cd or pushd

```
cd /d "C:\Files"
FOR %%i IN (*.*) DO (
echo %%~nxi
start "mass extract.." "C:\Files\extractor.exe" %%~nxi
)
```

**method #2**

Send the full path of each files with `%%i` (see `call /?` or `for /?`)

```
FOR %%i IN (C:\Files\*.*) DO (
echo "%%~i"
start "mass extract.." "C:\Files\extractor.exe" "%%~i"
)
```

**method #3**

specify in start the working directory.

```
FOR  %%i IN (C:\Files\*.*) DO (
echo %%~nxi
start "mass extract.." /D "C:\Files" "C:\Files\extractor.exe" %%~nxi
)
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
start "mass extract.." "C:\Files\extractor.exe" %%~nxi
```

try

```
start "mass extract.." "C:\Files\extractor.exe" %%i
```

This would pass full file path.

Also may I suggest adding the path's in quotes? In case your location has any spaces the above wouldn't work correctly.

```
FOR  %%i IN ("C:\Files\*.*")
```